# Searching nested json with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, search

got a question about searching json. I should know this but always get stuck on this one. Be very grateful for some help.

So I have a nested json object:

```
const myJson = {
  car: { wheel_type: "chrome" }
};
```

And I have a nested key of string:

```
const key = "car.wheel_type";
```

How do I extract the wheel type from the json object?

Comment: That is not json btw. Please use “JavaScript object” instead. :)

Comment: got it, found the answer https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Comment: Fab. I'm glad you found what you were looking for. Sorry I was unable to help.